# Calling a third party API in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I want to call a third party API in my controller and I want to use the returned values outside of the call. I am very new to Node and could not find anything useful as a solution.

I want it to work as follows:

```
exports.submit = async function(req, res) {
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://third/party/api/url',
    'headers': {
      'X-API-KEY': 'E6xwOg2BY4RbmiJogfyegrt746r7te',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) return error;
    var result = JSON.parse(response.body);
  });
  // I want to print/use 'result' here. how can I do that?
}
```

Please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Axios (https://github.com/axios/axios) and pass your options like:

```
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://third/party/api/url',
    'headers': {
      'X-API-KEY': 'E6xwOg2BY4RbmiJogfyegrt746r7te',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  const result = await axios(options);
  // You can print/use 'result' here.
```

Comment: this solution helps

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for the API calls, it is a promise based library.
If it is a production level code, then the best way is to create a service and handle all the business logic of API call in the service then just return the value back to controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the 'node-fetch' module such way:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const method = 'POST'
const url = 'https://third/party/api/url'
const headers = {
      'X-API-KEY': 'E6xwOg2BY4RbmiJogfyegrt746r7te',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

exports.submit = async function(req, res) {
    const body = JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'}) // your json data here
    const json = await fetch(url, {body, method, headers}).then(res=> res.json())
    console.log(json) // use it somehow 
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    res.end(json)
}
```